# 1 D Array multiplication

Tags: c

I'm unable to get expected output as per given input. Help me with the logic part of this code. I need to add up all prices and per bill amount, need t give discount and print resulted bill

Input:

```
3 2 150 3 65 1 1550.
```

expected output:

```
Bill amount 2045, discount 102, result 1943
```

my output:

```
bill amount 10590, discount 9531, amount to be paid 0
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n, a[10],i,j,b[10], r=0,p=0,q=0;
    printf("Enter the no of items\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter the no of units for item %d\n",i);
            scanf("%d",&a[i-1]);
            printf("Enter the price for item %d\n",i);
            scanf("%d",&b[i-1]);
        }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
                {
                    r+= (a[i-1]*(b[j-1]));
                }
        }
    if(r>5000)
        {
            p=(r-(0.1*r));
        }
    else if(r>2500 && r<5000)
        {
            p= (r-(0.08*r));
        }
    else if(r<2500)
        {
            p=r-(r*0.05);
        }
    printf("Bill Amount Rs.%d\nTotal Discount Amount Rs.%d\nTotal Amount to be \
    paid Rs.%d\n\nThank you for shopping with us.",r,p,q);
}
```

Comment: Please provide (in the question) sample input, expected output, actual output.

Comment: Why so many global variables?

Comment: The formatting/indentation is a bit......unsatisfactory:(

Comment: what exactly you are trying to get and where are you facing problem? Your question is not clear (to me ) .

Comment: Ah.... Barmar straightened it up:)

Comment: The single-letter var names are confusing, as are the loops starting at 1:(  Looping from 1 and indexing by subtracting 1 each time is just.. weird:(

Comment: With `p=(r-(0.1*r));` and `p= (r-(0.08*r));` and `p=r-(r*0.05);` but only `int` variables, no wonder you don't get the expected results.

Comment: This 'I'm unable to get expected output as per given input', without showing either, is going to get your question downvoted:(

Comment: If `n` is more than `10` then  `scanf("%d",&b[i-1]);` and `scanf("%d",&a[i-1]);` will be undefined behaviour.

Comment: ... so I suggest replacing `p = r-(0.1*r));` with `p = r * 9 / 10;` and so on.

Comment: What should the value of `p` be if `r` is 5000 or 2500? You don't include those values in any of your `if` statements?

Comment: @Barmar, I have added sample input, expected output, can you please use that input and check, Thanks in advance.

Comment: OMG trying to roll back to @Barmar edit but failed sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need nested loops. The two arrays work together in parallel, so just one loop will do it. You're multiplying the quantity by the prices of *all* the products, not just the product corresponding to that quantity.

And your code will be much simplified if you start your loops at `0` instead of `1`, since that's where array indexes start.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    r += a[i] * b[i];
}
```

It becomes more obvious if you used a single array of structures instead of multiple arrays:

```
struct item {
    int quantity;
    int price;
} items[10];
```

Then it would be clear that you just need a single loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    r += items[i].quantity * items[i].price;
}
```

The other problem is that you're setting `p` to the total amount minus the discount, not the discount. So

```
p = r - (r * 0.05);
```

should just be:

```
p = r * 0.05;
```

You do the subtraction later when you print `r - p`. The result of this is that you were displaying the total to be paid for the discount, and the discount for the total to be paid.

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/RMCN34357)

Comment: Thanks for that, I did change that, but the logic is still not correct and the output I get is wrong.

Comment: Doesn't this fix the problem with the bill amount?

Comment: No, It didn't fix it, can you please run it with mentioned input and check where did my logic go wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: I added a demo, it works. I also fixed the part that calculates the discount.

Comment: Thanks alot @Barmar, It had worked, can you please tell me where did I go wrong, so that i can learn it. and may be a way to ask you doubts directly. thanks in advance

Comment: The first line of the answer explains where you went wrong.

Comment: okay Thanks a lot brother. Is there any way, I can ask you doubts directly as I'm a beginner in coding?

Comment: Nope, I'm not volunteering to be anyone's tutor.

Comment: No issues, Thanks a lot brother.